# Restore Code Section after Inno installer extraction

Tags: inno-setup

i want to modify some dialogs of an inno installer, so i extracted the setup.exe with InnoExtractor and tried to compile the iss file with Inno Setup Compiler. Also there are serveral files, which were extracted next to this iss file.

But i can't compile it, because the complete [CODE] section is missing and some lines throws errors cause of missing functions. I read something about a dump_code.txt file, that is an extraction of "CompiledCode.bin", but it looks not really like common procedures.

Is there something i can do to get this section or isn't it possible cause it's an external setup file?

Comment: I do not think there's a tool that can decompile Inno Setup-made installer completely, in a way that you can make changes and compile it again easily. What are you trying to achieve exactly? What dialogs do you need to modify? Wouldn't it be easier to build a new installer (if you do not have sources of the existing one)?

Comment: That is not a bug, that is a feature :) Code section is protected and cannot be decompiled. Point.

Comment: @Slappy I do not think that's true. The code section is not deliberately protected. It's simply a compiled code. And as such it's difficult to decompile back into human understandable code. But it's not by purpose.

Answer (score -1):

You Can Use This:

[Inno Setup Decompiler](http://vdisasm.com/isd/)

Comment: This is not an answer, and shouldn't be posted as one. It might be an acceptable comment to the original question, if you had earned the comment privilege, but you have not yet done so. You *cannot* use this space to bypass not having the privilege, however. This space is for one purpose only, which is clearly explained by the bold title above it that says **Your Answer**.